# Complete markets and convenience yields

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, finance, government-debt, asset-pricing

I have been reading some papers on the safety/liquidity of US government debt and got a bit perplexed by the assumptions made in some of those papers. For example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304393221000945) by Mehrotra and Sergeyev have a reduced form way of capturing the convenience of government debt by adding government debt in the utility function. Yet, at the same time they assume complete markets and thus a unique stochastic discount factor. Here are the relevant quotes:

Markets are complete:

> Financial markets are dynamically complete, i.e., agents have access to government issued liquid bonds, safe bonds, which are non-liquid, and a risky security.12 The safe
> bonds are assumed to be in zero net supply. Equity—a claim on a Lucas tree that pays
> consumption goods at rate $y_t$—is in positive net supply that increases at the rate of population growth. There is no international trade in either goods or assets.

Convenience utility:

> The members of the household derive utility from consumption stream $\{c_t\}$ and from
> holding government bonds $\{b_t\}$. Formally, the utility function $(3)$ consists of two terms
> that capture the utility from consumption and utility from holding government bonds.
> The assumption that households have non-pecuniary preferences over government debt
> is a non-structural way to represent special features of government debt such as safety
> and liquidity. In our setting with a representative household, these preferences introduce a deviation from the Ricardian equivalence. As a result, changes in the supply of
> government bonds affect the interest rate paid on these bonds, and, hence, the cost of
> servicing the public debt.

I have seen other papers do the same or something similar and I guess a similar point applies in money in the utility function models.

This seems weird to me. Utility from government debt is usually microfounded in the setting of *incomplete markets*. Does this not lead to a tension in the reduced form and the corresponding microfounded models? My only answer is that government debt completes the *a priori* incomplete market, but I can't really justify this.

I know this question is vague. This is probably due to the fact that market completeness as a concept hasn't fully settled in my intuition. I would be more than happy with equally vague, but hopefully enlightening answers. Thanks in advance!